# Relation between two events

Tags: probability

In my book it is written as if A and B are two events such that P(B) is not equal to one , then $P(A\cap B) \ge P(A) + P(B)-1$

I could not understand how they have written this .

Can anybody explain me this

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\text {P (A n B)=P (A)+P (B)-P (A U B)} $ putting in the equation we have $1\geq \text {P (A UB) } $ which is true if the event B is not the universal set  ie it contains all the elements

Comment: To obtain $A \cap B$, type A \cap B when you are in math mode.  To obtain $A \cup B$, type A \cup B when you are in math mode.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the fact that: $$\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$$
and $$\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) \leq 1$$
(which yields $-\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) \geq -1$ that you can substitute in the first expression, after changing the sign).

I believe it was pointed out that $\mathbb{P}(B) \ne 1$ because the inequality would be trivial with $\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) = \mathbb{P}(B)=1$ (actually it would be an equality). But it isn't necessary.